# jquery traversing

Tags: jquery, compare, traversal

when i click on a link i take it's href value in a variable (the number represents an unique id), then...i have a separate ul:

```
<ul class="class_one">
   <li class="class_two"><a href="2345">some text</a></li>
   <li class="class_three"><a href="6789">some text</a></li>
</ul>
```

what i'm trying to do is to see if i have any "a" in my "ul" that has the same id that i stocked in my variable.

i tried something like this( of course with no result ):

```
$('ul.class_one').find('a[href="' + myVar + '"]')
//and if it finds no element do something
//i think is something wrong with the quotes ('a[href="' + myVar + '"]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried swapping your quotes?  jQuery might be using single quotes for attribute selection matching...

```
$('ul.class_one').find("a[href='" + myVar + "']");
```

From [jQuery Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEquals#attributevalue)

> An attribute value. Quotes are
>   optional in most cases, but should be
>   used to avoid conflicts when the value
>   contains characters like "]".
>   Variables can be used using the
>   following syntax: [name='" +MyVar+ "']

Comment: sorry...my bad,i mis-typed something. it works! thanks guys ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to remove the quotes altogether...

```
$('ul.class_one').find('a[href='+myVar+']');
```

Should work

Answer (score -2):

CSS, and jQuery by extension, uses single quotes.

```
$("ul.class_one").find("a[href='" + myVar + "']");
```

Comment: As with all JavaScript and CSS, you can interchangeably use single or double quotes as long as your boundary delimiters are of the same type.